# Como modificar o dados de um Column Chart ao clicar em uma seção de um Pie Chart? (Google Chart)

Tags: php, javascript, google-charts

A questão é a seguinte: Eu quero criar um Column Chart (ou modificar os dados de um Column Chart existente) ao clicar em um Pie Chart.
Já tentei modificar o Column Chart ao clicar no Pie Chart mas não acontece nada.

Desde já Obrigada!